# Code Concision - String Capitalization

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a few JavaScript functions for myself that I hope come in handy sometime.  The first I wrote was a Capitalization function (yeah i know, *real* original. whatever) 
I was just wondering if

1. I'm doing anything incredibly stupid
2. There's anyway to make the code below more concise (like cool JS concision features i don't know about, tightening down on program flow, etc.)
3. There's anything else cool i can do

Code:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(everyWord) {
    var words = this.split(" ");
    if (everyWord == true) {
        for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = cap(words[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        words[0] = cap(words[0]);
    }
    return words.join(" ");

    function cap(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }
};
var x = "abraham lincoln yada yada";
x = x.capitalize();
alert(x);
x = x.capitalize(true);
alert(x);
```

Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/LpwRn/31/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function capitalize(str, everyWord) {
    var r = /\b(\w)/
    if (everyWord) r = /\b(\w)/g
    return str.replace(r, function (c) { return c.toUpperCase(); });
}
```

Regexes can be convenient for situations like this one...

Comment: +1 for using string manipuation. although `this` is `window` so make it either of the `prototype` or pass in the `str` value.

Comment: @Raynos: OK, I switched to a classical function, instead, and I took in account  the everyWord parameter which I forgot initially... Thanks for the remark. Note: actually, my first attempt tested the built in JavaScript capitalize() function... :-(

Comment: if you are going for real concision, how about calling your param `ew` and saying: `var r=(ew)?/b(\w)/g:/\b(\w)/;`

Answer (score 4):

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/a8h3a/3/)

```
String.capitalize = function(str, everyWord) {
    return _.map(_.words(str), function(val, key) {
        return key === 0 || everyWord ? _.capitalize(val) : val;
    }).join(" ");
};
```

Write to `String` not `String.prototype`. Extending native prototypes is not friendly.

Use [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and [underscore.string](https://github.com/msy/underscore.string).

Basically don't re-invent the wheel ;)

Comment: but i *want* to reinvent the wheel. For my own learning purposes, and also so i can quickly grab my own code when i want it for a project instead of downloading something, etc.  Also, what's the actual advantage of not using prototype?  Other than not reinventing the wheel, anything else?  (Thanks, btw :-) )

Comment: @ThomasShields other code breaks if you edit the prototype (Classic `for ... in`

Comment: `Object.prototype` is the only one which breaks `for..in` if you add to it - you wouldn't/shouldn't need to use that operation with any other builtins. `Array.prototype` can be dicey in a mixed codebase purely because there are common methods people want to add, and they may clobber each other or get there first with a subtly different implementation. The rest of the builtin prototypes, I doubt anyone is that bothered about...

Comment: @insin `for (var i in "foobar")`. I just generally dislike editing prototypes on native objects because it adds undocumented features and generally confuses state.